# Maven plugin could not find artifact when using remote server

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

I'm trying to write my own maven plugin.  When I manually mvn install the plugin project, I can use it without a problem, but I'm having a problem retrieving it from our remote maven repository.  This error occurs if I delete the com/company/my-plugin from my .m2/repository directory and then try to do mvn install.

```
[WARNING] The POM for com.company:my-plugin:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.472s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Jun 19 16:15:29 EDT 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 4M/122M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Plugin com.company:my-plugin:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.company:my-plugin:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.company:my-plugin:pom:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]
```

The only reference to the plugin in the pom is in the build/plugins section:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <configuration>
        <sourceFiles>
            <sourceFile>infile.foo</sourceFile>
        </sourceFiles>
        <outputFile>outpath/myfile.foo</outputFile>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>my-goal</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

I've confirmed that the project exists in our remote repository and that other dependencies in that repository are resolving.  The other dependencies are not plugins, however.

Is there additional configuration I need to specify to resolve a plugin dependency?  Is there an approach I can use to help me figure out what's causing this problem more specifically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out I needed to separately specify the location of plugin repositories in the pom (in addition to specifying the remote repository normally).  I was missing the following block:

```
<pluginRepositories>
  <pluginRepository>
    <id>my-plugin-repo</id>
    <url>https://nexus.company.com:8443/path/to/repository/</url>
  </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Answer (score 0):

"[WARNING] The POM for com.company:my-plugin:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available"

Are you sure if the pom.xml for this plugin project exists in the plugin remote repository you are trying to pull from? If no, i probably think that should be the problem.

Comment: It definitely SEEMS to be there.  We're using a nexus server and I can see the pom and all the usual content I would expect for a normal maven deployment.